# Input двигаются

Tags: css, list, input

При вводе в input city, выпадает список городов из базы, когда выбираешь какой то город, input немного съезжает вниз, потом если повторить то input стоит ровно, если обновить страницу то все также, вопрос как исправить сдвиг input?

Comment: Скорей всего в css прописан отступ при сбросе фокуса или приобретении фокуса.

Comment: А как это исправить? Прописать input:focus: margin 0;

Comment: Когда вводим в текстовое поле какие-либо данные, оно стоит неподвижно. Но стоит нам выбрать что-нибудь из списка, то текстовое поле куда-то съезжает. Проблема скорее всего не в CSS, а в JS. Так как при клике по одному из пунктов, происходит JS событие, которое в свою очередь вставляет название города из списка в текстовое поле. И вот здесь и надо искать проблему.